# Will Windows 8 Metro support managed c++/cli

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, managed-c++, c++-cx

I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere, but will metro support managed c++ ?? Right now in Visual Studios 2012 RC it does not (in Metro only).

I have some frameworks written in c++/cli and wanted to port them to Metro. I know c++/cx is similar, but my c++/cli objects derive from ones written in C# and it would suck to have to rewrite that part of my system (but ok if I do, I just need to know where to go from here).

If there are plans to support it when Windows 8 actually comes out, I can wait.  Or if not I would like to know now so I can get to work on porting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++/CLI is not going to be supported in Metro as you can see here: [Windows Metro Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/7e117a9a-3e86-46f8-b53f-2163418479f2)