# Windows 8.1 Metro application in C++ (dae files)

Tags: c++, xml, windows-8.1

I JUST Dragged a DAE file into Windows 8 Visual Studio and it Renders it inside visual studio!!! Bloody nora! so it must be pretty tightly integrated!!! Any ideas of how to get that juicy information into something I can parse over for my directx game?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166877.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`System::Xml` is part of .NET... and from this earlier question it looks like the C++/CLI stuff which makes .NET libraries usable from (and creatable in) C++ is incompatible with Win8 Modern apps:

- [Will Windows 8 Metro support managed c++/cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693315/will-windows-8-metro-support-managed-c-cli)